# excel vlookup lookup_range cell contains a formula

Tags: excel, range, lookup, vlookup

I have a straightforward formula in Excel 2010 as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(D597,'Sheet1'!$AA$3:$AC$5000,3,FALSE)
```

The problem is the lookup_range, D597 in this case, contains a formula, not text or numbers (it is actually a reference to another sheet and cell).

The lookup is returning #N/A . I know the value is in the named range, column aa, and the value I want in column 3.

Is there a way to use vlookup, or another function, to accomplish this fairly straightforward lookup?

Comment: What is the formula or reference you're using for D597? and the value that it D597 returns, is it of type date? time? text? number?

Comment: And are you sure it's not suppose to be `=VLOOKUP(D597,Sheet1!$AA$3:$AC$5000,3,FALSE)`?

Answer (score 2):

With help from a friend, Master Joe, I was able to pull the value underlying D597 in the above vlookup formula. The solution:

```
VLOOKUP(VALUE(TRIM(D597)),'Sheet1'!$AA$3:$AC$5000,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: So you likely had a bumper space somewhere in that reference.

Comment: Could we please have the answer if the formula in that field resulted in a text answer? (ie. Non-numeric). E.g. =vlookup(A1, Sheet2!$A:$1:$B:$99, 2, False) 

...Then A1 to A99 might contain a formula. The formula might be: =IF($A1<>0,CONCAT($B1, " (",$A1, ")"),"")

....What is the opposite of "Value()"??
Thank you! :D